# Avoid black background during changing activities when calling setbackgroundresources(0) in the onPause?

Tags: android, layout, onpause

I have a problem that I wasn't able to fix, whenever I call the setbackgroundresources(0) on a layout in the onPause method there is a 1 second time where my background becomes black but all the others components remain. I'm trying to free up some memory and this is the only method that I tried till now. Is there anyway to avoid this kind of problem?

This is the code:

```
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

        relativelayout.setBackgroundResource(0);            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I've just figured out how to avoid that black background during activities switch! First of all I've decoded the background image of the XML layout with this code:

```
xmlbackground= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.xmlbackgroundimage);
```

Second, in the onPause method I've recycled the bitmap:

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();        
    xmlbackground.recycle();
    xmlbackground= null;
}
```

After this the Bitmap was recycled properly but when I was returning to this activity, my app would crash therefore I've fixed this issue with this lines of code:

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    if (xmlbackground== null || xmlbackground.isRecycled()){xmlbackground=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.xmlbackgroundimage);}

}
```

Now everything works fine and my memory management problem was fixed for now.

Answer (score 0):

To aoid you can set default background to your appliations in styles, In place of black screen it will show the image which you specified.. for ex.

```
<style name="Theme.FullScreen" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash1</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's still black.